# After optimized by llvm opt, all the code in the function has been deleted

Tags: optimization, llvm

There is a piece of llvm ir code, which is equivalent to "lea eax, [ebx + ecx]" in assembly :

```
@eax = internal global i32 0
@ecx = internal global i32 0
@ebx = internal global i32 0

define void @root() {
entry:
  %0 = load i32, i32* @ebx
  %1 = load i32, i32* @ecx
  %2 = mul i32 %1, 1
  %3 = add i32 %0, %2
  store i32 %3, i32* @eax
  ret void
}
```

No matter if I use opt -O3, -O2 or -O1, the result is like this:

```
define void @root() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  ret void
}
```

there is nothing in the function，what does it happen? Why does opt think the above codes in the function @root are useless codes ?

Comment: Possibly because the globals are internal, llvm detects your function has no externally visible effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler sees that those globals can only be used within the module, and nothing in the module either uses them or exports them outside the module, so writing to them is provably pointless.

LLVM will answer most questions of this kind using the `-print-after-all` option, which tells you which pass adds/changes/removes each instruction. The name of the pass usually tells you what the pass is trying to do.